# Storing Image pixel values in a 2D array using PHP and then access them using a loop

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, gd

I have this code that I tried to store Image pixel values in 2D Array and then try to access them so that I can recreate the same Image from the pixels stored in the array, the following was what I was trying to do but it only access the array in 1 Dimension, any who can help will much appreciate it

```
$resource = imagecreatefromjpeg("Broadway_tower_edit.jpg");
$width = 3;
$height = 3;

$arrayPixels = array();

//put pixels values in an array

for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {

    for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        // pixel color at (x, y)
        $color = imagecolorat($resource, $x, $y);



        $arrayPixels1 = array("$color");

       //$myArray[$x][$y] = array('item' => "$color");
        $arrayPixels[] = $arrayPixels1;

    }

}
//access pixel values an try to create a image

$img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);


for ($y = 0; $y < $height; ++$y) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; ++$x) {
        imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $arrayPixels[$y][$x]);
    }
}

// Dump the image to the browser
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg($img);

// Clean up after ourselves
imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is as you say, just the rows, you need to either build up each row and then add it to a list of rows

```
$arrayPixels = array();
//put pixels values in an array
for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    $row = array();
    for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        // pixel color at (x, y)
        $row[] = imagecolorat($resource, $x, $y);

    }
    $arrayPixels[] = $row;
}
```

or do the same as you do when you re-create the image and use the x and y co-ords...

```
//put pixels values in an array
for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        // pixel color at (x, y)
       $arrayPixels[$y][$x] = imagecolorat($resource, $x, $y);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Nigel Ren, Now  I an access the Index values in 2D, but another problem is its creates a black image instead of the same image I extracted  the index values from, can you or anyone help me with that too??

Comment: A couple of things to check, try displaying the image using the original image (`$resource`) to see if that shows up properly.  Using the second version (with $x and $y), compare the pixels in the first image and the second to see if they have been copied properly.